# Preventing rapid submission button clicks?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I found a solution like this but my onclick event is already tied to a code-behind handler:

```
MyButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(MyButton, "").ToString());

onclick="this.disabled=true;__doPostBack('MyContrl$MyButton','');"
```

My code:

```
<asp:imagebutton id="CheckoutBtn" runat="server" ImageURL="Styles/Images/submit.gif" onclick="CheckoutBtn_Click">
```

code-behind:

```
protected void CheckoutBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            {

                MyShoppingCart usersShoppingCart = new MyShoppingCart();
                if (usersShoppingCart.SubmitOrder(User.Identity.Name) == true)
                {
                    CheckOutHeader.InnerText = "Thank you.";
                    Message.Visible = false;
                    CheckoutBtn.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckOutHeader.InnerText = "Submission Failed - Please try again. ";
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi, I need to prevent a user from clicking a submit button multiple times as indicated in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Button serverside won't work, the Button will be disabled AFTER the PostBack, in this time the user can still click several times, disabling it in JavaScript `this.disabled=true;` is the only way to successfully do this.

Comment: And when then the server doesn't respond the user ends up with a broken page.

Answer (score 1):

Cases where you are trying to prevent the user from submitting a form multiple times are best handled using the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

It is a very simple pattern and Wikipedia does a good job of explaining it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to skip clicks that come within a certain TimeSpan of previous clicks.  Create a class variable "DataTime LastClickTime", initially set to DateTime.MinValue.  When you enter the click handler, check if DateTime.Now - LastClickTime > TimeSpan(...desired...) and if it isn't, exit the click handler with a return.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the button with javascript instead of disabling it server side?

```
<asp:imagebutton id="CheckoutBtn" runat="server" ImageURL="Styles/Images/submit.gif" onclick="CheckoutBtn_Click" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;">
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I don't think my CheckoutBtn_Click event will work because it will disable the button even at the first attempt.

Comment: Hmm? If you disable the button with javascript as shown, the following will happen - 1) The button will be disabled in the users browser, 2) a postback will occur, which fires CheckoutBtn_Click, 3) while that event is being run, the user will not be able to click on the button any further. 4) After the event is finished, you can either re-enable the button or redirect the user.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but instead of firing my CheckoutBtn_Click, it fires the Page_load in the code behind, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One way is hide the button from Javascript and show some ajax loader image.

```
function btnClientClick()
{
   document.getElementById('CheckoutBtn').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('dvLoader').style.display = '';
}
```